# How can I overwrite the onclick event in A tag?

Tags: jquery

I have this link in the top nav of my application:

```
<a class="nav" href="navigation.html?go=main" onClick="navigation('main'); return false;">Main Menu</a>
```

What I need to do is to overwrite using jQuery both the "href" and the "onclick" attributes so that whenever a user clicks on this link I show my custom alert.

Here's the code I have so far. However the problem is that the alert shows up for a fraction of a second and then the redirect to the main menu page still takes place for some reason:

```
$('.nav').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("href","#");
  $(this).attr("click","alert('TEST')");
});
```

Comment: It looks like the "onClick="navigation('main'); return false;"" line is the problem here. When I removed that code the jquery code started to work. However I can't modify this code as it's shared with other screen and need to be as is. So how do null out the onClick event?

Answer (score 1):

By using jQuery's [`event.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), passing in the `event` as an argument and calling `preventDefault()` on it:

```
$('.nav').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("href","#");
    $(this).attr("click","alert('TEST')");
});
```

Comment: We have the same last name!

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm still redirected back to the main menu page

Comment: Remove your browser's cache.

Comment: the "onClick="navigation('main'); return false;"" line is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write.

```
$('.nav').click( function() { 
    //do something
    return false;
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `return false`

```
$('.nav').click(function(event) {
   $(this).attr("href","#");
   $(this).attr("click","alert('TEST')");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm still redirected back to the main menu page

Answer (score 0):

you can try using live function

```
$(".nav").live('click',function(e){
   $(this).attr("href","#");
   $(this).attr("click","alert('TEST')");

    });
```

Comment: live is deprecated BTW this as nothing to do with OP question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/LZ6gx/

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("href", "#").attr("onClick", "alert('TEST');" + $(this).attr('onClick') + "");
    });
});
```